# Different 'div' heights in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a table whose cells contain div elements with different content, so they have different heights. Take this fiddle as an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/6btarubL/2/

As you can see, the code is really simple:

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="background-color: orange">
        DIV
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div style="background-color: aqua">
        Line 1<br>
        Line 2
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div style="background-color: #fac">
        10<br>
        20<br>
        30<br>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="background-color: #8f5">
        DIV
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div style="background-color: #cb1">
        Line 2.1<br>
        Line 2.2
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div style="background-color: #eda">
        10<br>
        20<br>
        30<br>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
tr {
  height: 100%;
}

td {
  vertical-align: top;
  min-width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
}

td div {
  height: 100%;
}
```

I'd like that the divs inside the cells took all the space, so they looked the same. Firefox does this, so its rendering is:

[image: Firefox 58 rendering]

Chrome, on the other side, doesn't obbey the `height : 100%` df the divs, so the rendering is:

[image: Chrome 63 rendering]

Then fun fact is that, if I remember correctly, Chrome was rendering it the same as Firefox until I updated to version 63 (I think I had version 59 before).

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: you can use `<td bgcolor="orange">`

Answer (score 1):

Please Change your this Css Code and Check again. Chrome

```
td {
  vertical-align: top;
  min-width: 150px;
  height:1;
}
```

Comment: I changed the code as you suggested, but it didn't make any change in Chrome and made Firefox to render it the way I don't want. Did it work for you? In this case, what version of Chrome and Firefox do you have?

Comment: I have use this Chrome Version 63.0.3239.132  and this code working perfectly

Comment: @Fel This works, but only when you put `display: flex` on your `tr` elements. Think he forgot about that part.

Comment: Yes! Adding `display: flex` to the `<tr>` element makes the code work. Please, could you explain why? I can't figure out...

Comment: @Fel adding `display: flex` to `tr` breaks the table display model and it is not correct solution.

Comment: @DeepakKumar can you add some unit to height property? `1px` for example. I got  63.0.3239.132 Chrome and without unit this code doesn't work.

Comment: @3rdthemagical, I've removed the `display: flex` property from the `<td>` element and added the 'px' unit to the `height: 1` in the `<td>` element and works in Chrome but not in Firefox. Did you try it in your Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The solution whas this CSS:</strike>

```
<!-- THIS CODE DOESN'T WORK -->
tr {
  display : flex;
  height: 100%;
}

td {
  vertical-align: top;
  min-width: 150px;
  height: 1;   
}

td div {
  height: 100%;
}
```

I'm right where I began. As @3rdthemagical pointed, the `display : flex` on `<tr>` breaks the layout and the columns aren't aligned. So, I did another test and these are the results:

WORKING CSS IN CHROME:

```
tr {
  height: 100%;
}

td {
  height: 1px;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

Sample output:

[image: Working code in Chrome]

The above code looks like this in Firefox:

[image: Right in Chrome - Wrong in Firefox]

WORKING CSS IN FIREFOX:

```
tr {
  height: 100%;
}

td {
  height: 100%;   /* <---------------- */
}

div {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

But, in Chrome I have the problem for which I started this question, so it looks like this:

[image: Right in Firefox - Wrong in Chrome]

Who's right? Chrome or Firefox? Isn't there a cross-browser solution for this?

I'll keep on investigating...

Comment: Solution by Deepak Kumar works perfectly. One improvement – use `height: 1px;` instead of `height: 1;.`

Answer (score 0):

HTML Change like below

```
<table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div style="background-color: orange">
                DIV
               <br>
               <br>
               <br>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="background-color: aqua">
                Line 1<br>
                Line 2<br>
               <br>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="background-color: #fac">
                10<br>
                20<br>
                30<br>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
            <td>
              <div style="background-color: #8f5">
                DIV
               <br>
               <br>
               <br>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="background-color: #cb1">
                Line 2.1<br>
                Line 2.2<br>
               <br>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div style="background-color: #eda">
                10<br>
                20<br>
                30<br>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use display flex

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6btarubL/6/)

**CSS**

```
tr {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

td {
  vertical-align: top;
  min-width: 150px;
}

td div {
  height: 100%;
}
```

With flex, you can center elements, align vertically, reorder, you can do a lot of stuff.

I have already tested in mozilla, you can use prefixes to have more compatibility:

```
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
```

Comment: Hi, I already tried this, but adding `display: flex` to the `tr` element breaks the column spacing consistency, so if one cell has a longer text, it's shown bigger and the table looks awful. Thanks anyway!

Comment: okay, to use `height: 100%` you need that the parent has a height set, so if you set a height in the table, the other `height: 100%` will work, like here: https://jsfiddle.net/6btarubL/8/

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the solution that worked for me was to use CSS conditionals and load different styles depending on the browser. I've explained it in this question:

[Load different CSS rule depending on the browser in an Angular 4 component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48505236/load-different-css-rule-depending-on-the-browser-in-an-angular-4-component/48518399#48518399)

Cheers,