# Load different CSS rule depending on the browser in an Angular 4 component

Tags: css, angular

I have an Angular 4 application that looks quite different depending on the browser you use. This is an example of how it looks on Firefox 58 (and it's the way I want it to look):

[image: App on Firefox 58]

And this is an example of how it looks on Chrome 63:

[image: App on Chrome]

I opened a question a few days ago to see if I could fix this issue ([Different 'div' heights in Chrome and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48441760/different-div-heights-in-chrome-and-firefox)) but I couldn't find a way to make it work for both browsers.

So, I'm thinking on loading a different CSS class depending on the user using Chrome or Firefox. Does Angular 4+ have a way of finding out the browser? What I would do then is to load the appropriate class using `ngClass` in the component's template that would, hopefully, fix the issue.

Or is there a better alternative?

Comment: Imo that sounds like a really bad idea. And looking at your other question I'm wondering why you'd use a table to begin with (unless of course it contains tabular data) and why not simply set the background color on the table cells instead of nested divs if you must use a table. If it's not tabular data but just a layout you're after then use flexbox.

Comment: I think I have a solution for your original question, take a look in my answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48441760/different-div-heights-in-chrome-and-firefox/48505398#48505398

Comment: I know it's an awful idea, but I can't find a cross-browser working solution. Although it's only a matter of changing `height: 100%;` (Working in Firefox) to `height: 1px` (Working in Chrome). There's a reason on why I use tables: it's a tabular layout, and each table cell has an 'object listbox' component where you can select and drag objects, so I need the column organization that provides a table...

Answer (score 6):

Doing some more research, I found the solution in this article:

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1167666/How-to-Apply-CSS-HACKS-for-Different-Browsers-Chro

In my case, this is the solution I used:

```
/* Style only for Google Chrome/Opera */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  td {
    height: 1px;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
}

/* Style only for Mozilla Firefox */
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  td {
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
}

/* Style only for Internet Explorer */ 
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
  td {
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
}
```

Thanks for all the suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

per the OP's question, yes you can detect browser (user agent) types by using `window.navigator.userAgent`. Learn more about it at [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/userAgent)

a rough function could look like:

```
getBrowser() {
  if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mozzila') != -1) {
      this.firefox = true;
  else {
      this.firefox = false;
  }
}
```

This will return browser specifications. Put this function in a service and you can call it during the `ngOnInit` hook in angular. Then you can dynamically add a css stylesheet you have created by adding it to the DOM

```
<link *ngIf="!firefox" rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/css">
```

alternately, you could create the style tag and append it to the DOM on the fly.

You could just use it for a single style in the css stylesheet like this:

```
<div class="title" [class.chrome]="!firefox">
```

> that sounds like a really bad idea

@powerbuoy is right, this is a bad idea. Not in function, but in how you want to put it into practice. This is not a very scalable method and will not work across many browsers. Other (better) css solutions include using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can have main file of styles, for example, `styles.scss`. And if you want to have styles for other browsers, for example, for `Internet Explorer 10-11`, then:

1. create new styles sheet, e.g. `InternetExplorer.scss`
2. then import this style sheet into main stylesheet file `styles.scss`:

   ```
   @import "scss/InternetExplorer.scss";
   ```
3. Then in `InternetExplorer.scss` write condition for Internet Explorer 10-11

   ```
   @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
       .nav-tabs .nav-item {
           margin-bottom: -1px;
           z-index: 0;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

it is not recommended to have different stylesheets per user agent, instead check if the browser supports the styling. you can check if a browser supports some style with the [@supports at-rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/@supports).

Since you haven't uploaded any code, I can
not tell you how to implement it in your case.

Answer (score 0):

it is not recommended to have different stylesheets per user agent. (maybe older versions of firefox does not support certain styling or chrome starts supporting it).

It is recomended to check if a browser supports some style. you can check if a browser supports some stlye with the [@supports at-rule.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@supports)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it showed me the way to find the solution :)

Comment: heads up to anyone considering this - `@supports` is not supported by IE, so this is not a great solution for something like replacing flexbox with floats if necessary.